# Javascript/small Jquery extension method to automatically alter Z-Indexes to put element on top of everything?

Tags: javascript, z-index

I was wondering if it is possible and if so if something exists that works with a stack of elements to put a relative element on top of *everything* else? (Z-index)

Something along the lines of:

```
$('myElement').moveToFront();
```

Provided my knowledge is accurate this would mean walking the tree of elements and altering Z-indexes such that the element and it's parents are on top of the others. I would rather not reinvent the wheel or find out that it is an impossible wheel to invent. Does something exist that does this?

Comment: It's not just the parent-child relationship that's important. You'd have to check the whole DOM. (And don't get me started about embedded frames ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that.

#### DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/insertusernamehere/KNB2f/

Note: The demo works only one way (didn't write the "restore"-function). If you have tried a link, reload the page.

#### Basic Idea

```
// clone the element and get its current position
var copy        = e.clone();
var position    = e.offset();

// set the position and a high z-index on the copy
copy    .css('position', 'absolute')
        .css('z-index', '1000')
        .css('top', position.top)
        .css('left', position.left);

// append the copy directly to the body
body.append( copy );

// hide the original element, but leave the document flow intact
e.css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Restore/undo this by:

- removing the copy
- show the original element again